# Manipulating lightning-input-field time field value

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-inputfield, time

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to manipulate value for  time field from javascript.

When loading a record with LDS the value of the time field is an integer represented in milliseconds, but when working with the field on lwc it's represented as string.

for example:

```
<lightning-input-field field-name="From__c" data-field="from"></lightning-input-field>
```

when accessing the field value it returns a string, such as:

```
const from = this.template.querySelector("[data-field=from]");
console.log({from: from.value}); // returns a string like: "00:00:00.000"
```

Is splitting the string to hours / minutes / seconds / ms and adding the values the only way to manipulate the value of the field?

Or is there another way to convert this string to either time in seconds / ms or maybe add / reduce time in another way?

Thank you!

Comment: [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/333129/lightninginput-update-time-value Does this answer your question?

Comment: this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, I know I can split the string and add separate values but I was hoping there's a better, more elegant way